# Magento 2 admin modal popup

Tags: magento2, admin, modal-popup

Looking for an example on how to create admin modal similar to what's used in advanced pricing on product edit. Does anyone have an example with basic block logic inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own in the end

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AdminModalPopup

Looked at a couple of examples in the core code such as the admin analytics notification modal and seemed overkill such as this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/AdminAnalytics/view/adminhtml/ui_component/admin_usage_notification.xml#L47

Hope it helps someone